# what the operator " &&" do in detail in the following snippet?

Tags: javascript, operators

I want to know why the property's value is not "true" in hash object, I assign the property into "true" in the statement " hash.jason = true ".

```
var array=[]

var array=[]

 hash.jason = true && array.push('jason')

 hash.tom = true && array.push('tom')

 hash.lucy = true && array.push('lucy')

the output is:

array
(3) ["jason", "tom", "lucy"]

hash
{jason: 1, tom: 2, lucy: 3}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

&& is logical AND.
Next, `array.push` returns length of updated array, so you assign it to hash. But, the same result you'll also get without `true &&`

```js
const array = [];
const hash = {};

// array.push itself returns length of
// updated array, so here you
// assign this length to hash
hash.jason = true && array.push('jason');
// But will not push to array if false
hash.tom = false && array.push('tom');
// Without 'true &&' will do the same
hash.lucy = array.push('lucy');

// Log
console.log(array)
console.log(hash)
```

Second part of your question - why it's assigning not `true` but `number`, see little code below... The logical AND expression is evaluated left to right, it is tested for possible "short-circuit" evaluation using the following rule: `(some falsy expression) && expr`

```js
console.log(true && 13);
console.log(false && 99);
```